# Oracle service cloud Rnow- pulling custom reports via api

Tags: oracle, rightnow-crm

Trying to pull custom reports in service cloud rnow. However, am not seeing the custom ones in the list. API returning only predefined reports.

Comment: This seems like something you should be taking up with Oracle Support.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have information about what API (REST, SOAP, Connect for PHP, Javascript, etc.) that you're attempting to use, the version of the API, and the version of your Service Cloud site.

However, the simplest solution across all APIs is probably a ROQL query.  You can get the report Ids from the query and then use the `queryReport` API calls with the appropriate ID to execute an individual report.

Example query for the REST API: `SELECT id, lookupName FROM analyticsReports where id > 99999` will return all the custom reports of your site.